# how to handle expired facebook access token to post activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, android-activity, facebook-opengraph, facebook-access-token

I've some problem when posting an activity to opengraph.. for example:

- user A login in my app and give a comment on article XX then the activity posted to their facebook profile
- then.. user A logout facebook, that will [automatically expired](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) their access_token
- user A still login in my app and give another comment and of course the activity will not posted to his facebook profile because he's logout from facebook

what I want to do is:

when user A logout facebook, then give a comment on article in my app.. then user A login facebook again the activity will posted to their facebook profile.. I'm sure this is posible.
because http://www.foodspotting.com/ can do that.. but I can't figured out how to do?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the official [Handling Invalid and Expired Access Tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration) guide? Start with that, if you still can't figure it out come back here.

Comment: Hi Nitzan,

I've already fixed it.. I already handle for that expired access_token by exchange that token. my bad.. I didn't enabled the "Remove offline_access permission" / "deprecated offline access" in my application setting :D

it's fixed now.. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're a web app, calling FB.getLoginStatus() in the JS SDK will get you a fresh access token.

Otherwise you need to pass the user through the authentication flow again.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/